# Easy way to calculate $(dd^c u)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $u$ be a $C^2$ function from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Define 
$$
\partial u = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial z_i}dz_i, \\
\overline{\partial} u = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}_i}d\overline{z}_i
$$
If $v = v' \wedge dz_i$, we can define $\partial v = \partial v' \wedge dz_i$, $\overline{\partial} v = \overline{\partial} v' \wedge dz_i$ and by analogy we can define such operators for $v = v'' \wedge d \overline{z}_i$. Next we define operators
$$
   d = \partial + \overline{\partial}, \;\;\; d^c = i(\overline{\partial} - \partial)
$$
We have $dd^c u = 2i \partial \overline{\partial} u$. I want to compute $n$-th exterior power of $dd^c u$. Is it possible to do it without direct calculations that involve change of summation variables?

Comment: Are $v'$ and $v''$ 1-forms?

Comment: @Mercy, $v'$ and $v''$ are functions for which operators $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$ are already defined. Then such operators are defined on $1$-forms and you can think of $v'$ and $v''$ as of $1$-forms to define it on $2$-forms

Comment: What is then the meaning of the notation $v'\wedge dz_i$?

Comment: @Mercy If $v'$ is a function, then $v' \wedge dz_i = v' dz_i$.

Comment: Not a common notation. I think you should just remove it! Just to make sure, by $n$-th exterior power of $\omega=dd^cu$ you mean $\omega\wedge\ldots\wedge\omega$ ($n$ times) right?

Comment: @Mercy Notation is from Kiselman's "Plurisubharmonic functions and potential theory in several complex variables", 1998, page 3. Furthermore, this notation is well used in differential geometry in MSU. I don't know why you don't like it. And $\omega^n = \omega \wedge \ldots \wedge \omega$ ($n$ times), you're right.

Answer (score 1):

If $u$ is $C^2$, then
$$(dd^c u)^n = n! \, 4^n \, \det \left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z_j\partial\bar z_k}\right)\,dV. $$

So, (ignoring constants that are usually irrelevant), $(dd^c u)^n$ is the determinant of the complex Hessian. The operator $(dd^c \cdot)^n$ is called the *complex Monge-Ampère operator* and plays a crucial role in pluripotential theory, the systematic study of plurisubharmonic  (psh) functions. It is possible to extend the domain of definition of $(dd^c \cdot)^n$ to some classes of non-smooth psh functions, but not to *all* psh functions. Finding the optimal domain of definition for the complex Monge-Ampère operator is a problem with a long complicated history and was only recently completely settled. (See Cegrell, *The General Definition of the Complex Monge-Ampère Operator*,  Ann. de l'Inst. Fourier, 54, (2004), p.159-179 and Blocki, *The domain of definition of the complex Monge-Ampère operator*, Amer. J. Math. 128 (2006), 519-530.)

**Added for the follow-up question** I think the easiest way to see that $(dd^c u)^n$ is a determinant, is to note that
$$\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_n$$
is an *alternating multilinear* form, almost by definition of the wedge product. The only alternating $n$-linear form on an $n$-dimensional vector space is (up to a constant multiple) the determinant. If you really need the constant, you have to plug in some cleverly chosen vectors to see what it is.

Comment: I know it. I only want to show this equality with determinant without direct calculations (I'm able to show it with direct calculations. My question is similar to question: is there an easy way to calculate laplacian in spherical coordinates - it is easy to do it but in general we have to write a lot).